# Access denied unless I add trailing /

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add wordpress as a subdirectory into rails, If I try to access the blog root page without trailing / or adding /index.php I get access denied.

```
https://example.com/blog 403

https://example.com/blog/ 200

https://example.com/blog/index.php 200
```

here is my conf:

```
location /blog {
  root /var/www/example/current;  

  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;   
  fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

location ~* \.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ { }
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

nginx error log:

```
Access to the script '/var/www/example/current/blog' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream
```

/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7 .js .css
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I am putting it here incase it might be useful for someone:

change: `location /blog` into `location /blog/`